# Is there a way I can make this fit the screen?

Tags: html, css, position

I am new to coding and I was wondering if there was a way that all the empty space a the bottom can be fixed

here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shrikhand&display=swap');
body {
    background-color: black;
    width:100%;
    height:100vw;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.title {
    font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    letter-spacing: 1.7px;
}

h1 {
    
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 1.01;
    margin-bottom:-600px;
    padding:0;
}



</style>

<body>


<div class="title" id="truth">
 <h1>I LOVE YOU  <br/>I LOVE YOU<br/> I LOVE YOU</h1>
 </div>
```

and here is the script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
  
     $("#truth").fadeOut(40000100);
 
});
function hidediv (){

document.getElementById("truth").style.visibility="hidden";
}

 setTimeout("location.href = '';",40999900);
</script>
```

again just wondering if the empty space at the bottom, below the text, can be taken away.
heres is my codepen https://codepen.io/amoney73/pen/VwrwQwW

Comment: You don't need to add `width: 100%` to the body since is a block level element so it  takes up the full width by default and the `height: 100vw` is what makes the page scrollable in the codepen so if you leave that out you will not have the extra space that makes it scrollable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `height:100vw;` from inside your `body {}` inside of your css.